# jQuery Frame Refresh for Live Updates

Tags: jquery, iframe, refresh, updates

I want to work on some Live Updates which is rendered in an iframe. This file called disp.php queries a table "posts" in the database and displays them all from bottom to top. Now when a new entry is added to "posts", I want it to be reflected real-time.

I could achieve it using

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

in the disp.php. But still the constant feel of refreshing is annoying. Now I'm trying to achieve the refresh this way, which doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Live Updates</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
function refreshLiveFrame() {
$('body', window.frames['myliveframe'].document).loadIfModified("disp.php");
setTimeout("refreshLiveFrame()", 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
refreshConsole();
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="myliveframe" src="disp.php">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a way for a live asynchronous refresh. Anybody's got a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Live Updates</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                refresh(); // Calling refresh() on document ready
                window.setInterval("refresh()", 10000); // Calling refresh() every 10 seconds
            });

            function refresh()
            {
                // Asynchonously requesting the content of disp.php
                $.get('disp.php', function(data)
                {
                    // This will be executed when you get the response back from the server
                    $('#posts').html(data);
                });
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="posts"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to achieve your goal using polling, it's a bad practice and, when possible, it's better to avoid it and use pushing instead. Polling means to continue to ask for a resource continuously until it's available. Pushing means that the resource itself will tell you as soon as it's available.

You can use pushing in this case by using jQuery like this:

```
$('iframe[name=myliveframe]').load(function()
{
    // This will be called every time the page inside the iframe has finished loading
    // $(this).contents() contains the page HTML
    // Use $(this).contents().find('body').html() if you want to read the content of the <body>
});
```

Comment: I just removed the iframe. Instead used a div to load the content of another page in that div.

    
    <script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
    $('#mydiv').load('disp.php');
    }, 10000);
    </script>
    </code>

Comment: Of course. :(. But then this does the work for me, for now.

And I wasn't able to get your code. If the function is executed everytime the page inside the iframe loads, how exactly can I use it? Say suppose, the iframe loads the page initially, then the function is called. And inside it I read the HTML content of the iframe. What can I do with it? Check for changes?

How exactly pushing? Help me out.

Comment: I wrongly understood your question, I've added another answer that should solve your problem. Still using polling, but at least the user won't notice it :) I don't have any experience using pushing in situations like this, but I will give you a keyword: comet